# PHP MVC - Is this the right way to do Model, View, Controller? Am I doing anything wrong?

Tags: php, authentication

I am fairly new to PHP and MVC. I don't want to use any frameworks like CodeIgniter or Laravel. I want to learn about this from scratch. I am trying to make a login page. So here is my code:

**HTML code:**

```
<html>
<body>

<h2></h2>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="text" name="password">
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Text.class.php code:**

```
<?php

    class Text {
        function __construct()
        {
        }

        private function sanitize($text) {
            $sanitizedText = htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES);
            return $sanitizedText;
        }
    }

?>
```

**Database connection code (connection.php):**

```
<?php
class Connection {

    public function dbc() {
        $host = 'localhost';
        $db = 'database1';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = 'password123';
        $charset = 'utf8';

        $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
        $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];
        return new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
    }
}
?>
```

**Controller code (LoginController.php):**

```
<?php
include_once('Text.class.php');

class LoginController {
    private $model;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->model = new LoginModel();
    }

    public function login($usernameOrEmail, $password) {
        $usernameOrEmail = sanitize($usernameOrEmail);
        $password = sanitize($password);

        if(!empty($usernameOrEmail) && !empty($password)) {
            if(isset($_POST['usernameOrEmail']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
                $usernameOrEmail = $_POST['usernameOrEmail'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $this->model->loginUser($usernameOrEmail, $password);
            } else {
                return "Please enter a username or password.";
                die();
            }
        } else {
            return "Please enter a username or password.";
            die();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Model code (LoginModel.php):**

```
<?php
include_once('connection.php');

class LoginModel() {
    private $dbc;

    private function loginUser($usernameOrEmail, $password) {
        $stmt = $this->dbc->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = :usernameOrEmail OR email = :usernameOrEmail AND password = :password");
        $stmt->bindParam(':usernameOrEmail', $usernameOrEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($row) {
            return "Login successful!"
        } else {
            return "Wrong username or password.";
            die();
    }
}
?>
```

Also I'm kind of stuck and I have 3 question:

1. In the HTML code, what do I put for action="" in the form tag?
2. In my class Text.class.php, what do I put in the __construct?
3. In my Model code, how an I pass the "Login successful!" or "Wrong username or password." to the view and insert it into the ""?

If you can, please tell answer my questions and tell me what im doing wrong (if I am doing anything wrong).

thanks everyone!

Comment: in your `login` method, why are you sanitizing those variables only to reassign them values from `_POST`?

Comment: your missing a key component, the front controller and router ( index.php and url routing ).  Besides that 1. `action="<?= $action; ?>"` or you can use a template system ( you may have to somehow include or load the HTML<view> into the controller code ), 2. nothing? does it need something. 3. is backwards you don't pass it from the controller to the model,  the model returns it to the controller.  You instantiate the model in the controller and ask it if the login is valid, it says yes or no .. etc.  via the return from `loginUser`

Comment: Yah, without some kind of URL router, your requests don't have any way of making it to the controller function you want to associate with them. You might want to look at one of the popular MVC frameworks either a) to use instead of the homerolled code you have or b) to study to see how they do it.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix So for #3, for the model, i would check if isset then run it through the database. After the database, it would return "Success" or "Wrong password" to the controller? If that's not it, can you please explain how to do this? thanks very much!

Comment: This line `$this->model->loginUser($usernameOrEmail, $password);` in the controller will return your result, and remove `die()` from the model. I would remove die from everywhere, but that's me.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Still very confused, sorry. Ok so when the user submits their username and password, the information is sent to the model directly or the controller? Based on what you said earlier in your first comment, it made it sound like it goes to the model first, then controller, then view. Can you please clarify? Thanks

Comment: Requests are routed to a controller, then the controller using models formats what it needs to or does what actions it needs to, then the results of that are rendered to the view.  1 controller, 1 or more models, 1 or more views ( pieces of a view ).   controler -> models -> view

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Ok, thanks. That's what I thought but you said `3. is backwards you don't pass it from the controller to the model, the model returns it to the controller.`. Can you please clarify? Thanks again

Comment: @jasonmoqio I applaud your choice to be a PHP MVC philosopher. I have a similar situation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172228/is-this-how-an-mvc-router-class-typically-works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Whatever you want.
2. Nothing, that class shouldn't even exists. The validation should be done in the *model layer*, preferable in the relevant *domain object*.
3. Your controller should pass the username and password to the authentication service (which is part of model layer). Then the view should require the information about user account from the authentication service (which would return `null` or an exception, if authentication failed).

Also, you should hash the user passwords or get a new hobby.